# Impossible to load nested routes in Angular 10+

Tags: angular, routes

Like I said in the title I have a problem with a nested routes in Angular.

When I hit the url */rules/disciplines* I want to load **RulesComponent** and **DisciplinesComponent** but I can only load the rules one.

I simply put a console.log("Rules/DisciplinesComponent loaded") in both component ngOnInit method and only the RulesComponent works.

This is my rules-routing.module.ts :

[image]

And this is my discipline-routing.module.ts

[image]

You can found the full code on my github : https://github.com/AntoineRenoux/BloodyNights-SPA/tree/dev/src/app/core/components/rules

Be carefull to select the "dev" branch.

Thx for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your source code you need to add a `<router-outlet>` to `RulesComponent` template else you cannot load children.

Comment: You're right ! Thx a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Also I have reviewed your code on github.  is not added on rules.component.html file.

I just explained some more about routing :

When we apply lazy loading on the module. Than also need to add  on the module component. Which component will display the child module. Because angular is a single page application.